# First item of a ng-repeat with a if condition

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
 <li ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-if="category.id== '3'">              
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.no == category.no" ng-style="{'margin-left': ($first ? '20px': '0px')}">
      ...
    </div>
</li>
```

it can only work on the very first item, but not every first item in each li. How can I update this?

Comment: What is `$first` ?

Comment: it is the first item of div under the first li now

Comment: I am thinking of using filter, but this is wrong syntax:
ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {item.no == category.no}"

Answer (score 0):

You need to try it like this. The way you were doing it $first refers to the first ng-repeat.

```
<li ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-if="category.id== '3'">              
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.no == category.no">
       // use $parent.$first to check for the first item of categories
       // using $first here refers to first item in items array 
       <div ng-style="{'margin-left': ($first ? '20px': '0px')}">...</div>
    </div>
</li>
```